# How to do "composition of c++" in c++/cli

Tags: oop, class, c++-cli, composition

I am facing trouble in doing containership in c++/cli. I have got two classes.One is a directory class with a data member "System::string^ path" and the other class is "file" with the data member"System::String ^ name". Now the idea is: directory contains a file(composition) and also, a directory may not have any file( dynamism). I am able to do create an inheritance relation , but obviously it doesn't make any sense. So i need a little help on how to create th above discribed relation between the two classes.

My second problem is: i am doing a project thet indexes all the contents of a specified path and then offers different searching methods.One of these methods is, "search by word". I will be limiting it to some 20 predifined words.Now i have to open a file(say a doc file) in the console and then do the string comparision. But i don't have any idea how to open the file in the console and also, how to do the comparision( i maen how a doc file will be treated as a file which is created by using console and how the words will be converted in System::String).

Hope i will get some help from you people:). One request :Kindly don't consider third party softwares as the solutions as i can't use them(BOOST libraries and Dirent.h...)

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 classes "Directory" and "File". "Directory" class can have other "Directory" and "File" objects.

In some circumstances, objects of "Directory" class and objects of "File class" **are treated as the same concept**, as an item contained by a "Directory".

Therefore, in some moment, **they act as if they where from the same class**.

So, why don't you create a base class called "FileSystemItem", and "Directory" and "File", are subclasses of "FileSystemItem". Add a function to "FileSystemItem" (enumerated), that returns when you want to know when an item it's one or the other.

The "Directory" class, have methods to add any "FileSystemItem".

Then , you instanciate a "Directory" object, and add items, wheter other directories or files. Later, you read the items, and check what they are.